# ASP.NET MVC avoid "pop-up window is blocked" (chrome, opera) during file downloading

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following code on backend side. (In order to get here client clicks button, hidden form with id is submitted, new blank page with ...\DownloadPDF address is opened and download is started).

Chrome and opera recognizes it as pop-up window and block it by default. In firefox this code is working. How to avoid it and make them treat it as not a pop-up window?

```
    public FileContentResult DownloadPDF(Guid id)
    {
        var model = service.GetById(Guid);
        var pdf = printService.CreatePDF(model);
        var fileName =(model.Name + ".pdf").Replace(" ", "_");
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename*=UTF-8''{Server.UrlEncode(fileName)}");
        return new FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf");
    }

Form that is submitted from front-end:
<form action="/Print/DownloadPDF" target="_blank" method="post" id="print-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="document-id" data-bind="value: Id"/>
</form>
```

Comment: That would depend on the user's popup blocker settings. Do you have to open a hidden form first? Why not have the link to the PDF on the page itself?

Comment: You mention that "a new blank page" is opened. How are you achieving that? Are you using window.open()?

Comment: I added frontend form into question

Comment: @Spivonious, I cannot do this, because I might not have Id when this button is clicked, so I need to save to database first than get id.

Comment: So the user could be uploading a file and then downloading it? How do they do the upload? Could you update a link with JS when you get the Id? There's nothing you can do in the code to disable the user's popup blocker.